# Possible to map a directory to another server (for independant Wordpress install)?

Tags: mod-rewrite, wordpress, mod-proxy, apache-2.4

We have EC2 instances that I would like to not contain a wordpress install, and instead ideally map a folder to a different server, and run it under the same domain.

For some reason, this is escaping me. My thoughts are to map that folder.

I have seen this question asked here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984834/map-virtual-directory-to-another-web-server-in-apache

And there were split opinions on Mod_proxy & mod_rewrite.

Is there another alternative to look into?

Reasons I am looking to keep wordpress off our server:
Traffic; Custom Configurations of SQL; Security; Possible incompatibilities with Apache configs, and Redundancy.

Comment: Why not use a subdomain like everyone else? Then you don't have to do all this insanity.

Comment: penalties to subdomains

Comment: What penalties to subdomains? Have you read some bad information about SEO on the Internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that mod_rewrite would work here. mod_proxy definitely will though, this is the way that we run it.

It can get tricky when running over SSL, we had to set some custom headers to get redirects sorted, but it's definitely possible to do it.

It's definitely worth trying to keep wordpress isolated - should help limit the damage if it's compromised.

Sample config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  <LocationMatch "/wordpress">
    ProxyPassMatch https://wordpress.example.com
  </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: We ran a wildcard domain SSL, so we could blog. subdomain to /folder; we tried mod proxy but found speed impacts.

so instead we put security policies on production servers preventing any data transfer, we then replicated the blog for a locked down admin server, and now we update patch, etc, there, then when done we git commit and use a deploy solution to push to our load balanced production servers.

Comment: @Daniel Scott...please share a sample config.